# Selenium is launching light version of Outlook Web App by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, outlook, outlook-web-app

I am currently having an issue where I am launching a selenium test on an AWS EC2 instance using RemoteWebDriver (headless).

For some strange reason, whenever the browser launches the Microsoft Outlook Web App, it is displaying the light version of the application. In the first screenshot below, the checkbox for 'Use the light version of Outlook Web App' is greyed out and I am not able to deselect it. After doing a login with such settings, the inbox from screenshot 2 appears.

I have tried to force deselect by running a javascript command to force it to be un-greyed, and then clicking on the checkbox, but it still launches the light version after that.

Launched elsewhere, on a VM and on my local machine, the Outlook Web App is the 'normal' version.

The impact from this issue is that the xpath locators and the verification process differs from the 'normal' version of the web app. Thus my scripts fail.

I would like to ask for directions on how to proceed, or if anyone has encountered this issue before?

*note that the screenshot for the login page below was taken from my local machine, which doesn't show the checkbox being greyed out. In the AWS instance, it is.

[image: Outlook Web App - Login Page]

[image: Outlook Web App - Inbox]

Comment: Look to see what browser user-agent string it is sending, tweaking this might give you the premium experience.

Comment: I've analysed the cookies being sent and premium version sends an additional: Set-Cookie:owacsdc=1; path=/; secure

Will investigate further. Thanks for the thoughts.